# Sumproduct across multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 19 normal sheets (named `P1` to `P19` ; yes, these are the name of sheets, not cells!), and one summary sheet. I want to calculate the sum of products of `M15` cells in normal sheets and `C2:C20` in summary sheet.

`('P1'!M15)*C2 + ('P2'!M15)*C3 + ... + ('P19'!M15)*C20`

This is what I write:

`=SUMPRODUCT(('P1:P19'!M15),(C2:C20))`

But it gives me `#REF!` error. Also, it automatically changes the contents to:

`=SUMPRODUCT(('P1:[P19]P19'!M15),(C2:C20))`

What should I do !?

Comment: looks like you dont have m15 referenced as a sheet either? Same with c2:c20

Comment: @DougCoats , `M15` is a cell in 19 sheets, that I want to sumproduct with `C2:C20` of the current sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

1) The below formula is placed within the Summary sheet

2) All sheet names are of the precise format "PX", where 1≤X≤19

3) Those sheet names are listed in A2:A20 of the Summary sheet

4) For each X, where 1≤X≤19, the sheet "PX" exists at all times

then:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(INDIRECT("'"&A2:A20&"'!M15")),C2:C20)`

Regards

Comment: Thanks @XORLX for your answer. It worked great. But one question: is it possible to write `1:19` instead of `1;2;...;19` !? I have a column in the summary sheet where I have entered the sheet names. `A2` to `A20` contain the names of sheets, `P1` to `P20`. Can we use them ?

Comment: Even better! Nice to know someone is setting up their worksheets sensibly! Have amended accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @XORLX . This is great. It worked like a charm. The funny thing is I had tried a similar code, only it didn't have `N` after `sumproduct` :D Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
=('P1'!M15*Summary!C3)+ ('P1'!M15*Summary!C4)
```